# RMSE of Training data is lower compared to test dataset

Tags: time-series, forecasting, error, lstm, univariate

First of all, this is not a case of Overfitting.
The task is to forecast Temp using univariate Single Step forecasting.

I have trained the LSTM model with on jena climate dataset(Dataset https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip.)
Following are steps

1. Extract Temp as a series
2. Divide in train(60000), test(5035) and Val(5000) data
3. Convert one-dimensional time series to a supervised model using lag features
   For example: Sequence 1 to 8 is converted with a window of 5 as below

## [[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]]   [6]

## [[[2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]]   [7]

## [[[3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]]   [8]

Code for it is...

```
def df_to_X_y(df, window_size=5):
  df_as_np = df.to_numpy()
  X = []
  y = []
  for i in range(len(df_as_np)-window_size):
    row = [[a] for a in df_as_np[i:i+window_size]]
    X.append(row)
    label = df_as_np[i+window_size]
    y.append(label)
  return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

3. Data is fed to LSTM mode by following the config

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(InputLayer((24, 1)))
model1.add(LSTM(64))
model1.add(Dense(8, 'relu'))
model1.add(Dense(1, 'linear'))

model1.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError(),MSE_matrics()])

history1 = model1.fit(X_train1, y_train1, validation_data=(X_val1, y_val1), epochs=10, callbacks=[cp1])

print(model1.evaluate(X_train1, y_train1))
print(model1.evaluate(X_val1, y_val1))
print(model1.evaluate(X_test1, y_test1))
```

This is going to print RMSE or SSE or any other but train error remains less compared to test error.

Experiment 2:
I tried different configs for train, test validation split
like, train(5000), Val(30000), test(5000)

Now in this cal train errors are less compared to the test.

**Question is:**

are these errors increasing with the number of samples? if so how we can report train-test-val error and confirm that model is doing well?